# How to slideshow through multiple jpegs/png

Tags: image, r, slider, slideshow

This is follow up question to this question: [mclapply vs for loops for plotting: speed and scalability focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12790504/mclapply-vs-for-loops-for-plotting-speed-and-scalability-focus)

If I have a bunch of images in the pattern "n_mu_stdev.jpeg", as given in Chase's solution to the above question, is there an R based method that allows some sort of slideshow with a slider according to the parameter values? From the packages that I have looked at most of the image readers tend read in the image as a data file and then re-plot it rather than just displaying a raw image, thus slowing it down dramatically...

I am not amazingly familiar with JavaScript, CSS or jQuery so if that is the proposed solution, then would probably need a step by step guide in terms of what to install etc.

one other solution i had considered was potentially uploading all individual images upon generation to a photo-sharing site like flickr or imgur (e.g kinda like in knitr), keeping note of the urls and then all the sliders do is choose which row of a dataframe to look at, which provides the correct url from which to get and display the image?...

Answer (score 2):

use jquery

Read the documentations

jquery library: http://jquery.com/
jquery slideshow plugin: http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/

Comment: any chance you can show me the working example as im not familiar with jquery or javascript at all...

Comment: here's the demo using the gallerific plugin http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/example-5.html

Comment: was kind hoping for a slider as well that allows me to control the various parameter...(there are 3 parameters)...

Comment: you can actually modify the plugin. As you can see from the demo, the image name is passed on the url. now what you have to do is pass all the parameters on the query string so you can control it.