# Parallel option giving different results

Tags: r, parallel-processing, plyr

This is related to my previous question [mclapply vs for loops for plotting: speed and scalability focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12790504/mclapply-vs-for-loops-for-plotting-speed-and-scalability-focus), I think I now have three/four ways of doing the same thing, but get different results even when setting the random seed.

Firstly...why are the results different...

Are `results2` and `results3` in effect doing the same thing?

Although not shown in the first example (it is shown below)...there are times that results2 takes longer than when not using the `.parrallel = TRUE` option, why is that?

```
> rm(list=ls())
> gc()
         used (Mb) gc trigger  (Mb) max used  (Mb)
Ncells 253264 13.6    1801024  96.2  1643320  87.8
Vcells 829208  6.4   22407472 171.0 28009341 213.7
> require(ggplot2)
Loading required package: ggplot2
> require(plyr)
Loading required package: plyr
> require(foreach)
Loading required package: foreach
foreach: simple, scalable parallel programming from Revolution Analytics
Use Revolution R for scalability, fault tolerance and more.
http://www.revolutionanalytics.com
> require(doMC)
Loading required package: doMC   
Loading required package: iterators
Loading required package: multicore
> registerDoMC(cores=4)
> gc()
          used (Mb) gc trigger  (Mb) max used  (Mb)
Ncells  409261 21.9    1440819  77.0  1643320  87.8
Vcells 1039134  8.0   17925977 136.8 28009341 213.7
> df <- expand.grid(i = 1:100, j = 1:2 , k = seq(100, 500, 100))
> params <- mapply(list, n = df[, 3], mu = df[, 1], stdev = df[,2], SIMPLIFY = F)
> ff <- function(tlist) {
+     set.seed(123)
+     n <- tlist$n
+     mu <- tlist$mu
+     stdev <- tlist$stdev
+     x1 <- c(1:n)
+     y1 <- rnorm(n,mu,stdev)
+     z1 <- data.frame(cbind(x1,y1))
+     ggplot(z1, aes(x=x1,y=y1))+
+         geom_point()+
+         labs(title=paste("n=",n,"mu=",mu, "stdev=",stdev))
+ }
> system.time(results <- llply(params, ff))
   user  system elapsed 
  5.363   0.009   5.368 
> system.time(results2 <- llply(params, ff,.parallel=TRUE))
   user  system elapsed 
  2.689   0.259   2.938 
> system.time(results3 <- mclapply(params, ff, mc.cores = 4, mc.preschedule = TRUE))
   user  system elapsed 
  7.488   0.685   2.501 
> identical(results,results2)
[1] FALSE
> identical(results,results3)
[1] FALSE
> identical(results2,results3)
[1] FALSE
```

comparisons:

```
require(rbenchmark)
benchmark(results <- llply(params, ff),
          results2 <- llply(params, ff,.parallel=TRUE), 
           results3 <- mclapply(params, ff, mc.cores = 4, mc.preschedule = TRUE),
             replications=5 )
```

giving the following results:

```
                                                                    test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
 1                                          results <- llply(params, ff)            5  27.869    1.521    27.833    0.043      0.000     0.000
 2                       results2 <- llply(params, ff, .parallel = TRUE)            5 109.990    6.003     5.455    2.472     37.565     7.048
 3 results3 <- mclapply(params, ff, mc.cores = 4, mc.preschedule = TRUE)            5  18.322    1.000     1.582    1.545     42.730    10.441
```

And even more weirdly when doing 10 replications instead of just 5....

```
 benchmark(results <- llply(params, ff),
      results2 <- llply(params, ff,.parallel=TRUE), 
      results3 <- mclapply(params, ff, mc.cores = 4, mc.preschedule = TRUE),
       replications=10 )
```

you get this:

```
                                                                     test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
  1                                          results <- llply(params, ff)           10  55.031    1.000    54.641    0.144      0.000     0.000
  2                       results2 <- llply(params, ff, .parallel = TRUE)           10 107.801    1.959     9.877    6.045     80.022    23.062
  3 results3 <- mclapply(params, ff, mc.cores = 4, mc.preschedule = TRUE)           10 297.556    5.407     3.576    5.624     96.493    31.035
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Just a thought but it takes time to set up a cluster.

Comment: I thought I am just using different cores rather than a different cluster....

Comment: also doesn't explain the differing results...

Comment: my understanding is that cores are kinda like separate processors.  it's not entirely different than running a computer lab in parallel in that you have to first bunch the cores/units into a cluster.  This is my non tech understanding and may be wrong.  Generally comments don't answer your question that's more the point of a comment.

Comment: fair enough...appreciate your thoughts though....thanks!

Comment: Can someone educate this non-multithread-user: what are those "user.self" "user.child" etc. columns -- is that all a report on core usage?  I'm trying to see where the output values in `results` and `results2` differ but I don't recognize any output data.  `identical` will report FALSE if there's any weedy little rounding or eps difference among the different processors.